# HTML - Passing parameters via POST to a Modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, post

Our code looks like this:

```
var result = window.showModalDialog("somepage.jsp?argument1=abc", 
                                     dialogArguments, 
                                     otherArgs);
if (result ...
```

I want to pass `argument1` in `POST` since it contains sensitive information.

Is it possible to open a modal dialog and pass to it a parameter in `POST`? How?

Comment: @Sarfraz The built-in [`showModalDialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog), I guess.

Comment: @RobW: Lol, forgot that, never used since a long time.

Comment: I can think of a crafty solution: Create a form in the dialog, and read the "sensitive information" from the `window.dialogArguments` object. Then, submit the form. Ta-daa.

Comment: Is it not possible to save the whole new dialog as a variable in original document? Then you can control it's inside elements and pass the variable that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for window.showModalDialog to use POST innately. You can, however, work around it by having it submit a form.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/iewebdevelopment/thread/126fcea8-c28b-49ce-ad49-65884ffabeb6

Alternatively, there are many other methods of doing a similar thing.