# ASP3 onclick Submit open a modal window

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

Can I know what is the best solution for my question. I got a data entry page with multiple input textbox inside a form on the main page. After enter and click the submit button, I want it to open the result page in a modal popup window.

Two different asp files.

1) Main.asp (Input)

2) Result.asp (get Input from Main to generate the result)

The main.asp is for data entry while the result.asp will retrieves the parameter pass by the main page for further processing and generate the result. The result.asp need to have a button to close the popup window and reset the main.asp textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can't POST a form directly into a modal window. Alternatively, you could:

- Intercept the JavaScript `form.onsubmit` event
- Manually build the querystring
- Open the modal with the informed parameters and,
- When the user closes it, clear the required fields on the main page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't really get it. Any sample coding for this method?

Comment: Sorry, no samples; but it will basically javascript code to intercept that event and build the querystring to your results page

Comment: I tried look around the suggestion you gave me but can't find a working solution which can pass parameter to modal window. However, it can open a modal window without problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mentioned that the solution you suggested actually can work but however, I need to pass the parameter as POST method instead of as URL parameter because the passing info is sensitive data.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079703/html-passing-parameters-via-post-to-a-modal-dialog

Comment: The method of showModalDialog cannot pass using POST method. I tried the other solution in the webpage too but not something I want.

I saw a website have this function and when I view the page source it include a few bootstrap library. However still unable to find a sample coding to explain such function.

Comment: If it's bootstrap, it isn't showModalDialog as this function is deprecated. Good luck!

Comment: I don't want to use showModalDialog because I tested it is not working. I need something else. I'll post my solution once I implement it. I'm implementing other features first and putting this one last.